How to use configuration in tasks?
I have a task in VSCode:
//  tasks.json
{   "label": "build debug",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
    "args": [
        "-g3",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}/../bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "${workspaceFolder}/test/${fileBasename}",
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.c",
        "-l_except"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "detail": "compiler: gcc",
}

Now I have 2 configurations ...
//  c_cpp_properties.json
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "debug",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
        },
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "defines": [
            "DEBUG=1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "release",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "DEBUG=0"
        ],
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
        },
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc"
    }
]

I saw an example that showed the adding a "configuration" key to the task:
    "configuration" : "debug",

I've tried that but it's not letting me use that key in my task - "configuration" is not allowed. How can I use a configuration in my task?
